# What armoured ground vehicles do the rebels use?

Tags: star-wars

Within the Battle of Hoth, rebel ground forces can be seen using snowspeeders to disable and destroy AT-ATs. I did not see any ground vehicles (such as hover tanks) being used.

My question is - were there any armoured vehicles that were effective against armoured vehicles such as AT-ATs or AT-STs?

EDIT: I am asking about at C-canon and above in legends (is there a different answer in the new disney canon?)

Comment: Snow speeders are what they had

Comment: Are you asking about such vehicles available *during the Battle of Hoth*, or available to the rebellion in general?

Comment: @Steve-O asking what ground vehicles were generally available

Comment: Also it might be helpful to specify a  canon level. I am sure there are some form of tanks in the video games! They did have a [Buick](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Buick) after all and surely that was a *tank*.

Comment: @Skooba I have just specified what canon

Comment: There's no such thing as C-canon anymore. It's all just Legends (i.e. non-canon) or canon. Please add the star-wars-legends tag if Legends is permissible. You've already received a Legends-only answer, though, so you'll probably need to ask a new question if you want canon only (so as not to invalidate the answer).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Rebel Alliance has been depicted using quite a variety of ground vehicles in various extended universe sources, here are the ones I know of as depicted in Video Games.

In *Star Wars: Galactic Battlegrounds* the Rebellion can construct 2 "Tank" vehicles: The T1-B hovertank is a small, shielded Anti-Infantry repulsor tank whereas the T3-B heavy attack tank is a tracked heavy tank designed for taking down larger vehicles and noted for being able to take on AT-AT walkers in open combat. The game also features a collection of generically designated artillery and anti-air weapons platforms. One of note appears to be the Mobile Proton Torpedo Launcher, an artillery platform that could fire while moving. These units also appear in Star Wars: Force Commander.

In *Star Wars: Empire At War* the Rebellion instead construct the T2-B repulsor tank which fulfills a similar anti-infantry role to the T1-B. IIRC the T2-B supposedly was designed originally as a mining transport, it's repulsors being to help it move over rough terrain and shields to protect it from landslides. Similarly the T4-B heavy tank is an "upgrade" of the T3-B and similarly is the Rebels' anti-vehicle tank in said game. Finally the rebels can also field the MPTL-2a deployable artillery, which unlike its predecessor the MPTL from *Galactic Battlegrounds* has to be deployed to fire. (Interestingly the T2-B seems to be the only Rebel tank to have appeared in a new canon source)

*Star Wars Battlefront 1* (2004) features the armoured hovercar Rebel Combat Speeder, which was apparently effective against both infantry and light vehicles. Also apparently appeared in Galactic Battlegrounds as a "Mech" unit.

*Star Wars: Battlefront 2* (2005) has the rebels using instead the AAC-1 speeder tank, which fills a similar role to the rebel combat speeder, although its large rotating missile pods give it a more tank-like form and presumably an easier time combating heavier vehicles, although it does not feature in the Hoth mission so there is no indication as to how it would deal with an AT-AT.

Sources: mostly Wookieepedia and personal experience with the games mentioned.
For the most part tanks were not fielded very often by the Rebellion as most of them were either smuggled on the down low from corporations sympathetic to the rebellion or had to be constructed by the rebels themselves.

Note: The Rebels did have other Anti-Vehicle units such as the dish turrets seen on Hoth in *The Empire Strikes Back* and Plex rocket soldiers which could also have been used to take down an AT-AT. Also according to *Star Wars: Empire at War* it was uncommon but not unheard of for an AT-PT artillery walker to fall into the Rebellion's hands, AT-PTs being very effective anti-vehicle walkers.

Sources: Wookieepedia, Gamefaqs, personal experience with several of the games mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

As of 2014, there are no levels of canon: Every story is valued equally and each can have an impact on another. According to Disney canon/Wookieepedia, the Rebel Alliance had a variety of armored ground vehicles at their disposal; they just weren't thought to be needed at the Battle of Hoth. Here are the ones that I could find/remember:

- Juggernaut - Originally a Legends vehicle, this huge tank was brought back in the canon mobile game *Star Wars: Commander*. They were good at breaking through strong defenses but vulnerable to massed infantry.
- Hover Tank - The Alliance used stolen Imperial combat assault tanks, most famously in the Battle for Tatooine.
- T2-B Repulsor Tank - These tanks were given to Rebel Alliance by treasonous military contractors. They fit the definition of the armored ground vehicles that you're looking for.
- Clone Wars-era Vehicles - The Rebel Alliance inherited a variety of armored ground vehicles from the war before it, including the Separatist AAT and the Republic AT-TE.

These are some of the more prominent examples. Feel free to edit this answer if you find better ones.